# What is the difference between a directory name that ends with a slash and one that does not?

Tags: files, filenames, slash

Is there any difference between a directory name such as

```
mydirectory
```

and

```
mydirectory/
```

I noticed this happens when I execute `ls` in some directories - some of the directory names have a slash and some don't. This is problematic because if I want to access a file contained in a directory, I may need to add a slash at the end:

```
vi $mydirectory"/"$myfile
```

or simply do

```
vi $mydirectory$myfile
```

Comment: This is a backslash: `\ `.  This is a forward slash: `/` (or just slash).

Comment: Files can not have a slash `/` ever: there are only 2 banned characters in Unix file-name (`/` and null). However sometimes a command like `ls -F` may add a `/` to the end of directory names. Sometimes you may choose to add them to the end of directory names to avoid ambiguity. E.g to dereference a symlink to directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without `/` it might also be a file.

In some situations it can be deadly. For example when using `mv`:

```
mv file1 mydirectory
mv file2 mydirectory
mv file3 mydirectory
```

All right? But if `mydirectory` did not exist or wasn't a directory, the final result is that `file1` and `file2` are gone and `file3` is now named `mydirectory`.

```
mv file1 mydirectory/
mv file2 mydirectory/
mv file3 mydirectory/
```

If `mydirectory` did not exist, all you get is three error messages and `file1`, `file2` and `file3` are still there.

So the `/` removes some ambiguity.

Apart from that there aren't really any rules. Some programs may behave differently depending whether you supplied the `/` at the end or not. It's up to them what to make of it.

In some cases you also get problems if you use too many `/`. For example `find` keeps surplus `/` in its output, which might trip you up if you try to find file/pathnames using simple string comparisons instead of, say, `realpath` or something.

Answer (score 3):

That would likely be a "display" thing with `ls`, i.e., if you do `ls -p` or `ls -F`, it should consistently add the slash after directories. It's essentially adding visual cues as to what it thinks the file is. (Do note that `-F` will also, e.g., append `@` to symlinks, `*` to files with executable permissions, `|` to named pipes, `=` to sockets and so on). You can also reproduce with `ls -d directory/` vs `ls -d directory`.

`/` and `\0` I believe is the only two characters not valid in a file/directory name.

Always adding the slash should be safe, if you've assigned mydirectory and myfile correctly, doing `vim "$mydirectory/$myfile"` should do what you expect. (With the caveat of `$mydirectory` and `$myfile` having been assigned correctly). `foo/bar` and `foo//bar` should be equivalent.

Generally; I really dislike assigning the output of ls to variables and dealing with it, primarily because I've previously been surprised about characters ending up into filenames combined with lacking quoting, ending up with destructive results. (I.e. `prefix=/home user=" oops" rm -rf $prefix$user`, which would end up recursively deleting `/home`, and then trying to recursively delete `./oops`).

Instead of using ls, I try when I can to rely on glob expansion by bash, or `find -print0 | xargs -0`. If you do use `ls`, ensure you're NOT using an existing alias for `ls`, and you use the display options that fits your particular task.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about directories or folders in the context of a "fancy filename" the folder is still a file but folder is rather a pointer to a container like a file folder in your filing cabinet, so if you denote or use a slash "/" or slash dot "/." it is helpful for a script to know an be sure you don't mean a file rather than a folder.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think you meant dot slash "./" which is "current folder" followed by a slash. slash dot would be "root folder" followed by "current folder".